# Play framework 2.0 Java - Defining model error and initial-data.yml

Tags: playframework-2.0

I was trying to build my own model and to populate it via the initial-data.yml.

here it is :

```
#Artists

artists:

    - !!models.Artist
        id: 1
        name: orelsan
        occupation: chanteur

#Records
records:
    - !!models.Record
        id: 1
        title: Le chant des sirenes
        vinylType: La classe
        pressInfo: a
        style: rap
        hits: 11
        artist: !!models.Artist
                    id: 1
```

And the different java files which describes the model : Record.java -

```
@Entity
public class Record extends Model{

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Required
    public String title;

    public String vinylType;

    public String pressInfo;

    public String style;

    @ManyToOne
    public Artist artist;

    public int hits;//Number of time played-consulted

    /**
     * Generic query helper for entity record with id Long
     */
    public static Finder<Long,Record> find = new Finder<Long, Record>(Long.class, Record.class);
}
```

Artist.java -

```
@Entity
public class Artist extends Model{

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Required
    public String name;

    @Required
    public String occupation;

    /**
     * Generic query helper for entity Computer with id Long
     */
    public static Finder<Long,Artist> find = new Finder<Long, Artist>(Long.class, Artist.class);

    public String toString(){
        return name;
    }

}
```

And running my app give me the following exception :

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception [PersistenceException: ERROR executing DML bindLog[] error[Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK_RECORD_ARTIST_1: PUBLIC.RECORD FOREIGN KEY(ARTIST_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.ARTIST(ID)"; SQL statement:\n insert into record (id, title, vinyl_type, press_info, style, hits, artist_id) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?) [23506-158]]]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:134) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:112) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:133) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.2]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:112) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:110) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0]
    at scala.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:277) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.2]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: ERROR executing DML bindLog[] error[Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK_RECORD_ARTIST_1: PUBLIC.RECORD FOREIGN KEY(ARTIST_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.ARTIST(ID)"; SQL statement:\n insert into record (id, title, vinyl_type, press_info, style, hits, artist_id) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?) [23506-158]]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dml.DmlBeanPersister.execute(DmlBeanPersister.java:116) ~[ebean.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dml.DmlBeanPersister.insert(DmlBeanPersister.java:76) ~[ebean.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersistExecute.executeInsertBean(DefaultPersistExecute.java:91) ~[ebean.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.PersistRequestBean.executeNow(PersistRequestBean.java:527) ~[ebean.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.PersistRequestBean.executeOrQueue(PersistRequestBean.java:557) ~[ebean.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.insert(DefaultPersister.java:404) ~[ebean.jar:na]
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK_RECORD_ARTIST_1: PUBLIC.RECORD FOREIGN KEY(ARTIST_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.ARTIST(ID)"; SQL statement:
insert into record (id, title, vinyl_type, press_info, style, hits, artist_id) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?) [23506-158]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329) ~[h2.jar:1.3.158]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169) ~[h2.jar:1.3.158]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146) ~[h2.jar:1.3.158]
    at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRowOwnTable(ConstraintReferential.java:345) ~[h2.jar:1.3.158]
    at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRow(ConstraintReferential.java:287) ~[h2.jar:1.3.158]
    at org.h2.table.Table.fireConstraints(Table.java:861) ~[h2.jar:1.3.158]
```

I really don't understand where does this comes from. I basically based my code to the ZenTask sample. Though it would work.

Does anybody has an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the right order for the Ebean.save in Global.java.  From your example above, I'd expect you'd save Artist before Record